Horror / Thriller film with a mother and her baby surviving after a virus has turned people into zombie-like killers
I know that there's at least a dozen films with a similar premise, but I'm failing to find this one. I watched it somewhere in the last decade or so, probably somewhere around the 2010s as a DVD borrowed from our local library. The film was in English. The protagonist is a caucasian female, I think in the United States. A virus has spread through the populace. The first symptom is a rasping cough and later, the virus causes the people to attack the uninfected, I think with a distinct cry when they sight prey that draws others in. The protagonist and her husband, on hearing about the outbreak, drove into the woods, where they have been surviving via scavenging, avoiding contact with anyone who might be carrying the infection. The husband goes on a scavenging mission and never comes back, leaving her with a baby and his gun, as well as I think their car, which may no longer run.
At some point, she makes a scavenging run, and gets trapped in a house with the infected, with her hiding in a chest freezer. I don't remember if that got them to go away due to lack of sightline, lack of scent, or maybe something involving body heat. At some point after that, she runs into another survivor, a man and his (adolescent?) daughter. Desperate for company (or maybe recognizing that she needs more people as support), she allows them into her camp. Something happens which she interprets as betrayal (it might have been betrayal) and she drives them off at gunpoint.
Some time after that, she's tending to her baby, who starts to emit the characteristic cough... and she euthanizes it. I don't recall how the film ended after that but I think it was one of those bleak endings where she realized that this was basically the end of humanity.
I remember the protagonist had long straight sandy-brown hair, although I'm not 100% on that. I think that the man she meets, and his daughter, had darker hair, maybe curly?

Here Alone (2016).

A young woman struggles to survive on her own in the wake of a mysterious epidemic that has killed much of society, and forced her deep into the unforgiving wilderness.

The film begins with the protagonist, Ann, already camping out alone in the woods somewhere in the US. We alternate between scenes set in the past, explaining her backstory, and scenes set in the present, moving the plot forward.
Through the flashbacks, we learn that there's been a viral outbreak that turns those infected into mindless, bloodthirsty savages (think 28 Days Later) referred to in the trailer as 'Afflicted.' Afflicted are normally silent, but start screeching when they sense the presence of humans and are drawn to noise and the scent of blood.
After learning of the outbreak, Ann and her husband, Jason, loaded their car with supplies and fled their home with their baby daughter, Hailey, to camp out in some woods that Jason used to play in as a child. Jason taught Ann survival skills, like how to use his rifle and what sort of berries to avoid eating.



He's later killed by Afflicted while looking for supplies, leaving Ann to fend for herself and Hailey alone. Some time after that, Ann leaves Hailey in her car while she raids a house for supplies, but has a run-in with an Afflicted and accidentally infects Hailey with Afflicted blood splattered on her jacket. After confirming that Hailey is infected, she makes the painful decision to euthanise her by feeding her baby formula mixed with ground-up aspirin pills. Although that scene is set in the past, it's shown very near the end of the film.
In the scenes set in the present, Ann encounters a teenage girl named Liv on a country road, next to her stepfather, Chris, who is injured and unconscious. She checks both for sores on the abdomen that indicate infection, and upon confirming that they aren't infected, helps Liv drag Chris back to her camp and nurse him back to health. After Chris regains consciousness, Ann is initially wary of him. He explains that he and Liv were heading north toward Canada, seeking refuge there, and that they'll move on in the morning, but a storm breaks out, causing them to stay with Ann longer.




 As Ann and Chris spend more time together, they grow closer and become sexually intimate. Liv notices this relationship developing and becomes increasingly jealous of and resentful toward Ann. Ann decides to head to Canada with Chris and Liv and they raid a house for supplies in preparation for the trip. Chris stays outside and lures the Afflicted in the area away while Ann and Liv sneak into the house. Liv takes the opportunity to knock Ann out with the butt of her rifle and tie her to a cupboard, then screams to lure the Afflicted back and slips out a window, leaving Ann for dead. Ann manages to free herself and hides from the Afflicted in a chest freezer. When she catches up to Chris and Liv, they're being attacked by Afflicted. Ann and Chris manage to kill the Afflicted but Chris is also killed. The film ends with Ann and Liv driving towards Canada together, distraught about what just happened.

Ann has light brown or ginger hair. Chris has light brown hair. Liv has thick, wavy, dark brown hair.




I can't view the trailer where I am right now, but that all sounds correct. I'm guessing that I got my sequence of events wrong for when the baby died. Thank you.
